# Are there compound words whose meanings would be changed once there is a change in stress?

Tags: meaning, compounds, word-stress, morphology

I have one true-or-false question.

> The different stress used in a compound do not usually affect the meaning of the compound.

The example used in my book to illustrate why this statement is false is the word “red coat”. While I know it means a coat that is red when its second syllable is stressed, and it means a British soldier especially in America during the Revolutionary War when the first syllable is stressed, It seems to me the "fact" that it is a phrase not a compound word anymore when it means a coat that is red can't be the proof of the falsehood of the statement.

IN SUMMARY

1. Is the example wrong in the sense that “red coat” which means a coat that is red is a noun phrase? If "red coat” which means a coat that is red is a compound word, then my question would be how to distinguish a phrase from an open compound.
2. Is my understanding of this statement wrong? I suppose it’s false to say that the change of a stress affect the meaning of the compound word when there is no compound word.
3. Is the statement wrong? If my understanding is right, and the example in my book is wrong, then I need other examples to illustrate the truth value of the statement. My question would be whether there are compound words whose meanings would be changed once there is a change in stress?

Comment: Don't you have other examples? If not, how can you be confused? :)

Comment: @Lambie I am confused about three points. 
1. Is the example wrong in the sense that “red coat” which means a coat that is red is a noun phrase? 
2. Is my understanding of this statement wrong? I suppose it’s false to say that the change of a stress affect the meaning of the compound word if there is no compound word.
3. Is the statement wrong? If my understanding is right, and the example in my book is wrong, then I need other examples to illustrate the truth value of the statement.

Comment: The problem with red coat is that the American Revolution ones were: Redcoats. :) When I speak and say: The Redcoats are coming., I hear no difference with: Ok, kids wear the red coats not the blue ones.

Comment: @Lambie I think I didn't explain well. My problem with "red coat" is that the change of a stress makes it a phrase instead of a compound word. The statement claims that the change of a meaning affect the meaning of a compound word, but if it's not a compound word anymore, then the example doesn't explain the statement.

Comment: I just told you what I think. There is no difference in stress for me. And I gave an example of each. And I think this question is probably going to fall under "opinion", for red coat and Redcoat.

Comment: I will disagree slightly with @Lambie. It is true that when I say "The Redcoats are coming" (note: no space) the emphasis is on *red*. And it is true that when I am comparing "The red coat or the blue one?" the emphasis is again on *red*. But when I say "Your red coat goes so well with your hair" both *red* and *coat* receive the same stress.

Comment: @randomhead Any expression at all that contrasts two minimal things will stress the difference: The **big** car or the **small** car? The same is true for: The **red** coat or the **blue** coat. But that is a different point.

Comment: The wording of the quoted passage is poor. If taken literally, the "redcoat" example does not illustrate it. It would be better phrased: "*Some compound nouns have fixed stress patterns, and to deviate gives a new meaning altogether*"

Comment: The **dining** room and the **living** room. Only stressed if asking a question. or making a point in contrast to each other.

Comment: Since the document talks about stressed syllables, it must be referring to verbal speech. Verbally, you can’t automatically tell if it’s one word or two.

Answer (score 0):

The table at the bottom of [this page](http://enwiki.org/w/Compound_%26_phrasal_stress) has more examples, including "hot dog", for which the stress affects the meaning.

Comment: I think my main problem with this question is that I understand the stress could affect the meaning of a word, but I don’t see how it could affect the meaning of a compound when the change of a stress makes a compound word a noun phrase. I think what I am looking for is a polysemic compound word whose stressed syllable is different.

Comment: I think if the stress on a word like ***'tax-pay-er*** was switched to ***tax-'pay-er*** that would significantly change the meaning, in that the latter version would very specifically imply contrast between those who ***pay*** tax and those who ***receive*** State benefits (funded by the payer) and/or those who ***avoid paying*** their due taxes ("tax dodgers"). The standard stress pattern carries no such implication.